# How can I read in a csv file as a MultiIndexed DataFrame when the spanning column header isn't repeated?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of .csv files that I would like to read in as MultiIndexed DataFrames, but the spanning column header isn't repeated and so I am left with two headers rather than a MultiIndex.

A test.csv file:

```
A,,B,,C,
a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2
1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2
```

When I run the following,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=[0,1])
print(df)
```

the structure that is returned isn't what I'm looking for:

```
   A Unnamed: 1_level_0  B Unnamed: 3_level_0  C Unnamed: 5_level_0
  a1                 a2 b1                 b2 c1                 c2
0  1                  1  1                  1  1                  1
1  2                  2  2                  2  2                  2
```

I want a MultiIndex with the first column header acting as follows:

```
   A     B     C 
  a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2
0  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Is there a way to read in the csv as-is such that I get the desired structure? If not, is the most efficient way to do this just to modify the csv files so that they explicitly repeat the outside header values like so?

```
A,A,B,B,C,C
a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2
1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do that in a one-liner, but you can fix it afterwards in python, rather than manually editing files.

First create a `Series` from the first `level` of the `MultiIndex`, making sure to order the values by the order given in the `labels`:

```
level_0 = pd.Series(df.columns.levels[0][df.columns.labels[0]])
```

Then convert the `'Unnamed: *'` values to `None` and do a `fillna` forwards:

```
level_0[level_0.str.startswith('Unnamed: ')] = None
level_0 = level_0.fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

Finally assign the series `values` and `index` as `levels` and `labels` of the `DataFrame`:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels = [level_0.values,
                                     df.columns.levels[1]],
                           labels = [level_0.index,
                                     df.columns.labels[1]])
```

Comment: My apologies, I mistook the time stamps and did not realize that you responded first. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help little trick - first [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) without header `header=None`, then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) first row, create new `multiindex` from first and second row, remove these rows and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""A,,B,,C,
a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2
1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=",", index_col=None, header=None)
print df
#    0    1   2    3   4    5
#0   A  NaN   B  NaN   C  NaN
#1  a1   a2  b1   b2  c1   c2
#2   1    1   1    1   1    1
#3   2    2   2    2   2    2

df.ix[0,:] = df.ix[0,:].fillna(method='ffill')
print df
#    0   1   2   3   4   5
#0   A   A   B   B   C   C
#1  a1  a2  b1  b2  c1  c2
#2   1   1   1   1   1   1
#3   2   2   2   2   2   2

print zip(df.ix[0,:], df.ix[1,:])
#[('A', 'a1'), ('A', 'a2'), ('B', 'b1'), ('B', 'b2'), ('C', 'c1'), ('C', 'c2')]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(df.ix[0,:], df.ix[1,:]))
df = df.ix[2:].reset_index(drop=True)

print df
#   A     B     C   
#  a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 c2
#0  1  1  1  1  1  1
#1  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked as needed.

Comment: Don't see how this is better than my answer, which was the first correct one.

Comment: This answer is also wrong as it gives columns of dtype object, not integer.

Comment: I think your answer is very good. You can try add comment under question for `Kelly Moran` and maybe she change accepting to your answer. But it depends of her.